# Census Tracts for Puerto Rico

Tags: geospatial, us-census, census

I'm looking for digital data for Puerto Rico. Specifically census tract shapefiles from the 1990 & 1980 census. TIA

Comment: did you look on the census bureau web site?

Comment: The only thing I could find for PR was from 1992, but I have no idea what these files are!!! ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER1992/72/

Comment: The closest I got was https://www.census.gov/main/www/cen1990.html and several of the links there are broken. This info may not be online, at least not on census.gov. https://www.nhgis.org/user-resources/data-availability also suggests 1980 census tract data isn't available for Puerto Rico and notes that the Census didn't cover the entire USA until 1990.

Answer (score 1):

As referenced by Barry Carter's comment on the question, there isn't a straightforward answer to this question.

As described [in this Census Bureau page](https://www.census.gov/history/www/programs/geography/tracts_and_block_numbering_areas.html), the entire US was not partitioned into Census Tracts until the year 2000.  (In 1990, the whole country was covered by either tracts or the now-defunct Block Numbering Area, or BNA).

Those deeply interested in Puerto Rico may wish to read [Understanding Census Geography In The Tiger Data Base: The Case Of Puerto Rico](https://msaag.aag.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/19_Sperling.pdf) (PDF), a 1991 paper by Jonathan Sperling, of the Census Bureau's Geography Division. In it, he writes:

> Reflecting the rapid urban expansion in Puerto Rico over the past few
>   decades, the 1990 census shows that 56 of the 78 municipios are
>   covered by census tracts compared with 22 in 1980 and only 8 in 1970.

which reinforces that, in Puerto Rico, specifically, census tracts were sparse before 2000.

Typically, for questions like this, I'd direct someone to NHGIS.org, but when I downloaded the 1980 Census Tract shapefiles (there are two versions), neither included Puerto Rico.

If NHGIS doesn't have it, you probably have your work cut out for you.